# Count values in column that have only letters

Tags: sql, teradata

How Can I count rows in column where values have only letters ? For exmaple if I have this table:

```
| ID | Age | FULL_NAME |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| 0  | 23    | Jason12 |
| 1  | 11    | SamOG. |
| 2  | 57    | Alexx |
```

And when I run the query i want to get something like this:

```
| Numerator | Denominator | 
|:---- |:------:| 
| 1  | 3    |
```

Numerator are the rows where value is only build with letters and Denominator is count(*). Let's say that my DB name is CUSTOMERS. I use Teradata SQL Assistant. Any ideas how I can do it ? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: tag your dbms name please

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Right now something like this: Select Customer as rule, count(case FULL_NAME when '%[^a-z]%' then 1 else null end) as numerator, count(*) as denominator from DataBase; Count for numerator is mass of different answers on stack.

Comment: DBMS name not db name @neekitit

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin Added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use REGEXP_INSTR() like below

```
select sum(case when REGEXP_INSTR(FULL_NAME,'[0-9]')<>0 then 1 else 0 end)
as Numerator
 ,count(1) as Denominator from table_name
```

Comment: I get: Syntax Error, expected something like a 'SUCCEEDS' keyword ora ' MEETS' keyword or a 'PRECEDES' keyword or an 'IN' keyword or a 'CONTAINS' keyword between ')' and '|'.

Comment: Use `<>` instead of `!=`

Comment: @neekitit follow the instruction that dnoeth suggested